# ActiveResource MassAssignmentSecurity error with Timestamp fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I am trying to implement basic CRUD operations with ActiveResource on a rails model.
The documentation says to make a sub-class of `ActiveResource::Base` and then set `self.site`.

This works well UNTIL I try to update an existing record that has been fetched.
The error I see is a '`MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`' which appears when I call the `'save()'` method on my ActiveResource object due to the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are not accessible.

I found if mark those fields with `attr_accessible` on my model class it works ok, but that seems quite an insecure and pretty poor solution.
Below shows an example of the issue:

```
rails new TestApp
cd TestApp
rails generate scaffold User first:string last:string
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

On a different terminal tab I use:

```
irb
require 'active_resource'
class User < ActiveResource::Base
self.site = 'http://localhost:3000'
end
u = User.new()
u.first = 'John'
u.last = 'Shine'
u.save()
#This saves ok
nu = User.find(1)
nu.first = 'Geoff'
nu.save() 
#This never works
```

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to discard the Timestamp fields and have rails create them automatically (as normal) I would get the data from a new json/xml template inside the app which doe not include the Timestamp fields.

Also assuming you have access to the app which is providing the data you could add something like the below to your rails model to test, it overrides (could call it 'uses') the as_json method for the json template.

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

This will update the timestamp fileds by the rails server itself.

Alternatively you should have a look at RABL and jbuilder as both are great options.